# Time-dependent covariates- is there something wrong with this code? (R program)

Tags: r, cox-regression

I am checking a few of my Cox multivariate regression analyses' proportional hazard assumptions using time-dependent co-variates, using the `survival` package.  The question is looking at survival in groups with different ADAMTS13 levels (a type of enzyme).

Could I check if something is wrong with my code itself?  It keeps saying `Error in tt(TMAdata$ADAMTS13level.f) : could not find function "tt"` . Why?

Notably, `ADAMTS13level.f` is a factor variable.

```
cox_multivariate_survival_ADAMTS13 <- coxph(Surv(TMAdata$Daysalive, TMAdata$'Dead=1')
                                                        ~TMAdata$ADAMTS13level.f
                                                        +TMAdata$`Age at diagnosis`
                                                        +TMAdata$CCIwithoutage
                                                        +TMAdata$Gender.f
                                                        +TMAdata$`Peak Creatinine`
                                                        +TMAdata$DICorcrit.f,
                                                        tt(TMAdata$ADAMTS13level.f), 
                                                        tt = function(x, t, ...)
                                                        {mtrx <- model.matrix(~x)[,-1] 
                                                         mtrx * log(t)})
```

Thanks- starting with the fundamentals of my actual code or typos- I have tried different permutations to no avail yet.

Comment: From the document of `?coxph`, `tt` is an "optional list of time-transform functions". You are directly providing a function, so would recommend creating a named function and passing that through a list. Or it seems you just want to create weights from `tt`, so just define `tt` before the call to `coxph`.

Comment: Also, your time transformations don't seem to contribute to your model, and because you are using unnamed parameters, I think your `tt` function *call* will be taken as the value of `data` and its *definition* as the value of `weights`.  I doubt that's what you meant.  Also, TMAdata$`Dead=1` looks strange, but without a reproducible example, it's impossible to be sure if it's a problem.  If you specify `data=TMAdata`, you won't need to specify `TMAData$` in front of every term in your model.  It's usually a good idea to start simple and add complexity in stages to be sure all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Limey was on the right track!

The time-transformed version of `ADAMTS13level.f` needs to be added to the model, instead of being separated into a separate argument of `coxph(...)`.

The form of `coxph` call when testing the time-dependent categorical variables is described in [How to use the timeSplitter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Greg/vignettes/timeSplitter.html) by Max Gordon.

Other helpful documentation:

[coxph - fit proportional hazards regression model](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.2-13/topics/coxph)

```r
cox_multivariate_survival_ADAMTS13 <- 
  coxph(
    Surv(
      Daysalive,
      'Dead=1'
    ) ~
      ADAMTS13level.f
    + `Age at diagnosis`
    + CCIwithoutage
    + Gender.f
    + `Peak Creatinine`
    + DICorcrit.f
    + tt(ADAMTS13level.f), 
    tt = function(x, t, ...) {
      mtrx <- model.matrix(~x)[,-1]
      mtrx * log(t)
    },
    data = TMAdata
  )
```

p.s. with the original data, there was also a problem because `Daysalive` included a zero (0) value, which eventually resulted in an 'infinite predictor' error from `coxph`, probably because `tt` transformed the data using a `log(t)`. (https://rdrr.io/github/therneau/survival/src/R/coxph.R)

Comment: yes, you're right!

Comment: Hi David, apologies as I did not have time to get back to this earlier.  You were right on the money (but David very kindly talked to me personally as we're friends...)